# How does python access the apiClient of k8s through socks5 proxy

Tags: python, kubernetes, urllib3, socks5

Accessing k8s apiclient is successful without using a proxy, as follows:

```py
configuration = client. Configuration()
configuration.verify_ssl = False
configuration.host = "xxx"
configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + self.token}
c = api_client. ApiClient(configuration=configuration)
api = core_v1_api.CoreV1Api(c)
# Query the namespace, the step is successful
result = api.list_namespace()
```

However, since k8s api is automatically generated, the socks proxy cannot be directly set:https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1064

Since k8s uses restClient, there is no way to pass the socks5 proxy. Currently, this method is used to connect, but it is invalid:

```py
configuration = client. Configuration()
configuration.verify_ssl = False
configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + self.token}
configuration.host = "xxx"
c = api_client. ApiClient(configuration=configuration)
proxy = "socks5://xxx:1080"
c.rest_client.pool_manager = self.build_socks_proxy_manager(configuration)
api = core_v1_api.CoreV1Api(c)
# Query namespace, this step timed out, unable to connect
result = api.list_namespace()

def build_socks_proxy_manager(self, configuration, pools_size=4, maxsize=None):
  # skip some initialization steps
  return SOCKSProxyManager(num_pools=pools_size,
                    maxsize=maxsize,
                    cert_reqs = cert_reqs,
                    ca_certs=ca_certs,
                    cert_file=configuration.cert_file,
                    key_file=configuration.key_file,
                    proxy_url=configuration.proxy,
                    **addition_pool_args)
```

Updated based on larsks answer:

```py
configuration = client. Configuration()
configuration.verify_ssl = False
configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + self.token}
configuration.host = "xxx"
c = api_client. ApiClient(configuration=configuration)
proxy = "socks5://xxx:1080"
c.rest_client.pool_manager = SOCKSProxyManager(proxy_url=proxy)
api = core_v1_api.CoreV1Api(c)
# Query namespace, this step still timed out, unable to connect
result = api.list_namespace()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `configuration.host` to the `socks5://` url, but that doesn't make any sense (the `socks5://` url is the address of the *proxy*, not the  remote server).

You would expect to set `configuration.proxy`, except that this will fail when you call create an `ApiClient`.

If you set the `pool_manager` *after* instantiating the client object it seems to work. That is, if I have a socks5 proxy running on `localhost:2080`, the following code will connect via the proxy:

```py
import os
from kubernetes import client, config
from urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager

configuration = client.Configuration()
configuration.verify_ssl = False
configuration.api_key = {
    "authorization": "Bearer ...",
}
configuration.host = "https://api.example.com:6443"
c = client.ApiClient(configuration=configuration)
c.rest_client.pool_manager = SOCKSProxyManager(proxy_url="socks5h://localhost:2080")
api = client.CoreV1Api(c)
print(api.list_namespaced_pod('example-namespace'))
```

Comment: First of all thank you.My host here is a virtual address, and the socks proxy will resolve it from the virtual address. I updated the proxy of the configuration to the socks proxy address, but I still can't connect after updating according to your method.

Comment: Note that you should be using `socks5h://` instead of `socks5://` (this pushes DNS resolution to the proxy). What happens if you use this code *exactly*, replacing only the host address, the proxy address, and the bearer token?

Comment: Thanks. I discovered through packet capture that the TLS protocol failed because the CA was unknown and the connection was reset. It finally succeeded after explicitly specifying verify_ssl = False when setting up SOCKSProxyManager.